# Removing brackets from a string

Tags: ruby

```rb
def encode(string)
    string.unpack("B*").to_s.gsub("1", "b").to_s.gsub("0", "a")
end

puts encode("Michael")
```

The output is: ["abaabbababbabaababbaaabbabbabaaaabbaaaababbaabababbabbaa"]

Ive tired a bunch of stuff to remove the brackets. I know gsub would prob work but that doesnt look that good. Also im sure there is a better way. I tired using .shift with no luck. also tired .to_a.shift. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: [`string.unpack` returns an array](https://apidock.com/ruby/String/unpack). If you want to only perform your encoding on the first value extracted from the input string, simply use `string.unpack("B*").first`. If you want to perform your encoding on each value, you should _expect_ that your result will be an array

Answer (score 4):

The "problem" is you're converting an array to string. The result of unpack is returning an array, and you're invoking to_s in that, so you get:

```
p "Michael".unpack("B*") # ["01001101011010010110001101101000011000010110010101101100"]
p "Michael".unpack("B*").to_s # "[\"01001101011010010110001101101000011000010110010101101100\"]"
```

You can simply get the first and only one result, without needing to apply to_s, and you'll be able to do the replacements you need:

```
"Michael".unpack("B*").first.gsub("1", "b").to_s.gsub("0", "a")
# "abaabbababbabaababbaaabbabbabaaaabbaaaababbaabababbabbaa"
```

Notice if you're just replacing 0 with a, and 1 with b, you can use `tr`:

```
p "Michael".unpack("B*").first.tr("01", "ab")
# "abaabbababbabaababbaaabbabbabaaaabbaaaababbaabababbabbaa"
```

Same result.

Comment: `String#unpack1`, if available, is preferable: `p "Michael".unpack1("B*").tr("01", "ab")`